# Handling Multi-Version Software Release?

Tags: team-foundation-server

I have a simple VS project which references DLLs which must be specific to a version of the software I am integrating with and I need to release my project for multiple versions of the software - 2015 & 2016.

So I need to build MyProject2015.DLL and MyProject2016.DLL - let's pretend each must reference Application2015.DLL and Application2016.DLL for the sake of example. I want to maintain a single code base. I'm using Team Foundation Sever 2015 for version control. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the assistance of a colleague I resolved this issue by using two projects which referenced the same classes but utilized different references.

First, I removed the project from the solution. I then copied the csproj file and renamed each with the version numbers:

- myProject 2015.csproj
- myProject 2016.csproj

Next I added each project back to the solution in VS. I like to keep a folder with referenced DLLs with the project so they are checked-in to TFS and another developer has the correct versions referenced when pulling down the project. So I created a v2015 and v2016 folder for the respective projects placing the appropriate DLLs in each. I then removed the existing references in the projects and re-added them, pointing to the files in the version-ed folders. [Resulting project tree](https://www.screencast.com/t/jl2bWQ092VW).

Now I still have two additional build configurations, one for each version. I made sure each mapped to version-ed bin folders (bin\2015 & bin\2016). I also added an AssemblyName tag in the csproj files so that my DLL for each build gets a name that includes the version number. Finally, in the Build Configuration Manager, I selected only the 2015 project for the 2015 build and likewise for the 2016 build. Here is the [build config section of the csproj files](https://www.screencast.com/t/bgruoWfaUEA).

Now, when I open a class in the 2015 project and then try to open the same class in the 2016 project, it opens the same class file in the IDE.

UPDATE 11/06/2019: I have been informed the visual studio project type of Shared Project is for exactly this scenario. I have created a new solution which has one shared project that holds all my classes. Then I have multiple class library projects for each version I need built. Each of these projects references the shared project and has its own references to each third party versioned DLL it utilizes. This solution has been much better suited to including a Unit Test project as well.

Comment: If it opens the same class file, how do you distinguish the code differences, if any, between each version?

Comment: I believe this is going to work (I'll need to get my 2016 environment set up to be certain). I defined a [different compilation symbol](https://www.screencast.com/t/RmFVL9VW3AI) on each project. Then, if necessary, I can place version specific code in [#if #elif blocks](https://www.screencast.com/t/0N5S5Ek8).

Comment: Allow me to add that I do not presently expect my code to require differences based on the version. The libraries I reference are stable. However, if that turns out to be wrong in the future, I'm sure an analysis would take place as compiler directives are added to determine when two completely separate projects would be appropriate.

Comment: I've been reading Working Effectively with Legacy Code by Michael Feathers and I realize I write procedural code with no unit tests. So I tried adding a Unit Test project to this concept and it is not going well. I added a reference to my 2015 version project to the Unit Test project and tried to write a Test Method. I'm getting the "Could not load file or assembly" on one of the version dependent DLLs.

Comment: The previously mentioned "FileNotFoundException" is specific to the application with which I am integrating - Dynamics GP. It was resolved thanks to Tim Wappat's blog post: http://timwappat.info/post/2017/04/18/Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-MicrosoftDexterityBridgedll-or-one-of-its-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar with 32 bit and 64 bit builds

You can setup you project file to use different references based on build configuration

http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/changing-project-s-references-based-on-the-build-configuration

Then you can run the build in build configuration X on your build server to get the right output.

Its annoying that you have to build more than once to get one complete output (in my case a nuget package with both dlls) but you can cobble chains of stuff together in team city to make it all happen. Not sure about TFS

Comment: I have attempted this by making two folders in my project & including the different versions of the references DLLs in them. I have then create two new build configurations and added a custom tag for the location of the DLL. [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/37dKWGyGQ2b3) The completed build for 2016 is still referencing the 2015 version of Application.Dynamics.DLL. I've used ILSpy on the built DLL to verify this. Could this be due to search order for references and the reference to the 2015 DLL is located before the HintPath is searched?

Comment: dont include both dlls in the final package, just the one you want

Comment: also, dont thet have different file names? sounds like there is a mistake in there somewhere

Comment: The files do not have different names for each version. [GP 2015](https://www.screencast.com/t/V99dGpb9) vs [GP 2016](https://www.screencast.com/t/zGLYUVSamit) I'm uncertain how I am doing this differently than your description or what you mean by your first comment. Here is the : [Project tree](https://www.screencast.com/t/8CQybGFF) in case that gives you a clue. What else can I provide that might help?

Comment: I mean if your bin folder doesnt contain both files it will be impossible to reference the wrong one

Comment: The bin folder does not contain both files after building. What are you seeing in what I've shared that makes you think so, please?

Comment: you said after the build it referenced the wrong version. how would that be possible if the wrong version didnt exist?

Comment: According to [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manishagarwal/2005/09/28/resolving-file-references-in-team-build-part-2/) there is a search order in resolving references. If we look back at the [project file](https://www.screencast.com/t/wcbbQmnhiqSV) you'll see I have created a new tag in both build configs for the path to each version of the Application.Dynamics.dll and then used that tag in the HintPath of the Reference. What can you find fault in that I've done different than your blog post on the topic?

Comment: it sounds like you are just running it in VS and have both dlls present, rather than building it on a build server and running the resultant applicaiton, which should only include the appropriate dll

Comment: Are you saying I should not expect to be able to build in VS on my machine where both application DLLs are present?

Comment: It says in the blog post that VS reports the wrong ref in the solution window, also with both files have the same name, I think you would have to add some extra factor, maybe required version? to ensure that the correct one was picked up. As you note, its only a Hint path and there are two things at play, the one it builds against and the one it finds when it runs

Comment: I'm aware of the comment about VS reporting the wrong reference when viewing the solution. I expected that would not matter if the build process identified the proper file based on this setup. I expected the resulting project DLL in the bin folder to reference the correct application DLL. It does not as evidenced by decompiling the project DLL with ILSpy and by the fact that the wrong application DLL is copied to the bin folder.

Comment: what can i say, it worked for me